# Facebook Debugger returns 404 but curl works

Tags: php, facebook, debugging, curl, http-status-code-404

I used the [facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) to check my page and it shows me `Response Code 404` but for me it works.

**curl works**

I tested with browser and curl (from other server). GET and POST return `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`:

```
curl -i http://www.mypage.de/stuff/test.html
curl -i -X POST http://www.mypage.de/stuff/test.html
```

**Page is valid**

I check my test.html using http://validator.w3.org/ and got `This document was successfully checked as XHTML + RDFa!`

**Response header**

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:497
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Mon, 10 Mar 2014 16:13:15 GMT
ETag:"28a0b29-353-4f4429866eebc"
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=99
Last-Modified:Mon, 10 Mar 2014 15:52:48 GMT
Server:Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

**Why does facebook get a 404?**

**Update**

If I look at access logs all request reach the server but the 404 access come from default instead of the correct virtual host.

If I use the IP in facebook instead of dns it works normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it was a DNS problem after all. We changed the primary and secondary DNS from our own to the hosters and after one day it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the server logs if you have a hit like

```
facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)
```

Its likely that your .htaccess is blocking the Facebook crawler.

Comment: Good point. I looked at logs and updated the question. First I thought it is just a broken DNS record but it looks more like broken apache config...

Answer (score 1):

the default vhost is used, if the hostname of the machine is equivalent to the request hostname. You can set `ServerName somethig-different-from-hostname` in the default vhost or disable the default vhost with `a2dissite default` to prevent this